# POSIX Semaphores in C for using in 2 seperated programs (consumer/producer)

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, semaphore

I'm trying to implement the producer/consumer problem in C. I know how to handle it with "fork", but in this case I shall implement two programs. One for producer and one for consumer.
For producer: a semaphore has to be initialized and in a loop (to 100), the semaphore shall increment its value and print it. This already works fine.
For consumer: the semaphore initialized in producer, shall be opened and in a loop (to 10) its value shall be decremented and printed. 
When I run the process for consumer: a memory-access error is printed.
I have absolutely no idea, what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for any help!

consumer:

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main() {
    int value;
    sem_t *mySem = sem_open("sem",  O_CREAT|O_EXCL , S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR , 0); 

    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        sem_wait(mySem);
        sem_getvalue(mySem, &value); 
        printf("The value of the semaphore is %d\n", value);
    }
    sem_close(mySem);
    sem_unlink("sem");
    return 0;
}
```

producer:

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

sem_t sem;

int main() {
    sem_init(&sem, 0, 0);
    int value; 
    for(int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
        sleep(1);
        sem_post(&sem);
        sem_getvalue(&sem, &value); 
        printf("The value of the semaphore is %d\n", value);
    }

    sem_destroy(&sem);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You attempt to create the semaphore in the consumer, but don't even check if it was successful or not. In the producer, you use an internal semaphore not connected in any way to the semaphore in the consumer. Start there. Write the programs so that they only open and close and unlink the semaphore, with full error checking. Don't add any features before it compiles without warnings, when full warnings are enabled, and runs without issues. That way you progress step by step, and *know* what new part caused an error or a failure.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, what do you expect `sem_init(&sem, 0, 0);` to do?  What relationship does that `sem` have with the consumer?

For two unrelated processes to communicate over *any*n IPC, they have to agree on a resource by name.  That's true if they share a file.  It's also true if they share a semaphore.  That's what named semaphores are for.

I modified your programs to use one named semaphore.  The producer creates it and owns it exclusively; the consumer errors out if it's not there.

Consumer:

```
#include <err.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

static const char name[] = "sem";

int main() {
    int value;

    sem_t *sem = sem_open(name, 0, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR, 0);
    if( sem == SEM_FAILED ) {
      err(EXIT_FAILURE, "sem_open");
    }

    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        sem_wait(sem);
        sem_getvalue(sem, &value); 
        printf("The value of the semaphore is %d\n", value);
    }
    if( -1 == sem_close(sem) ) {
      err(EXIT_FAILURE, "sem_close");
    }
    if( -1 == sem_unlink(name) ) {
      err(EXIT_FAILURE, "sem_unlink");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Producer:

```
#include <err.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static const char name[] = "sem";

int main() {
    sem_unlink(name); // ignore error if not extant
    int value; 

    sem_t *sem = sem_open(name, O_CREAT|O_EXCL, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR, 0);
    if( sem == SEM_FAILED ) {
      err(EXIT_FAILURE, "sem_open");
    }

    for(int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
        sleep(1);
        sem_post(sem);
        sem_getvalue(sem, &value); 
        printf("The value of the semaphore is %d\n", value);
    }

    sem_destroy(sem);
    return 0;
}
```

I think you'll find they work better now.  I recommend you follow my lead, though, and check every return code, and exit on error whenever anything goes wrong.  For trial code like this, that's the quickest way to get it running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for correction. This works perfectly for my purpose.
With sem_init I supposed to initialize the semaphore with 0 as Start-Value.
Seems like the error was using this instead of a pointer and sem_open in the producer-process.
This was my first experience with named semaphores, so it was not easy to see my error.

Thank you very much